# How to filter out duplicate rows on a certain dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like:

```
                             price     is_peak is_valley
2018-08-25 01:47:00+00:00    0.041838  True    False
2018-08-25 05:21:00+00:00    0.041620  True    False
2018-08-25 09:11:00+00:00    0.041599  True    False
2018-08-25 12:37:00+00:00    0.041670  True    False
```

All rows are either is_peak = True or is_valley = True

How do I filter this to remove rows where:
- the previous row is a peak and the current row is a peak; or 
- the previous row is a valley and the current row is a valley?

I tried the following:

```
merged = pd.concat([ peakT, valleyT ])

mask = (merged['is_valley'] & merged.shift(-1)['is_valley'] == False) | (merged['is_peak'] & merged.shift(-1)['is_peak'] == False)
merged[ mask ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because *All rows are either is_peak = True or is_valley = True* you can use `ne` to search where `is_peak` is different from the previous row:

```
df.loc[df.is_peak.ne(df.is_peak.shift())]
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question so that you understand the logic:

```
df[~((df['is_peak'] & df['is_peak'].shift())  # Previous row is a peak and the current row is a peak.
     | (df['is_valley'] & df['is_valley'].shift()))]  # OR the previous row is a valley and the current row is a valley.
```

The `~` character inverses the mask, so it returns everything that does not match the condition.

The logic of the condition is ((A and B) or (C and D)).  Note that `&` is bitwise AND, and `|` is bitwise OR.